# node async only calls first function when inside node-lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lambda, aws-lambda

Using a vanilla node script like the following node async works just fine:

```
async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
    function (c) {
        console.log(1);
        c(null);
    },        
    function (c) {
        console.log(2);
        c(null);
    }       
  ]);
```

The above when run via `node test.js` prints out:

```
1
2
```

... as expected.

However if I place the code inside a node-lambda handler:

```
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = function( event, context ) {
  console.log( "==================================");

  async.waterfall([
    function (c) {
        console.log(1);
        c(null);
    },        
    function (c) {
        console.log(2);
        c(null);
    }        
  ]);

  console.log( "==================================");
  context.done( );
}
```

Only the first method is called when I run `./node_modules/.bin/node-lambda run`

```
==================================
1
==================================
```

I'm using:

- async 1.5.2,
- node 5.5.0
- node-lambda 0.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using asynchronous code.
Apparently that code `context.done( );` to finish the executing of the main function `handler` and other async code(second function in waterfall) cannot be executed, it did not have time enough, because the main function has been completed.

Comment: @keithgould I've update the answer. Try to remove `context.done( );` to test

Comment: Boom! That was it @isvforall. Thank you.